# How to use ASCIIFoldingFilter with QueryParser

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm running the latest version of Lucene.Net (3.0.3). (I've also tagged `lucene` because it is basically the same architecture ...)

I have following `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Analyzer` class:

```
public sealed class LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer : Lucene.Net.Analysis.KeywordAnalyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName,
                                            TextReader reader)
    {
        var keywordTokenizer = base.TokenStream(fieldName,
                                                reader);
        var asciiFoldingFilter = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(keywordTokenizer);
        var lowerCaseFilter = new LowerCaseFilter(asciiFoldingFilter);

        return lowerCaseFilter;
    }
}
```

This analyzer removes, beside the different cases, any special characters - so that eg `Außendienst` becomes `aussendienst`.

Now I want to search this field with a "prefixQuery" (I have tried `Lucene.Net.Search.PrefixQuery` before, but this class does not allow any injection of an analyzer). I now do this like so:

```
var escapedLowerCaseSearchPattern = QueryParser.Escape(searchPattern);
var prefixEscapedLowerCaseSearchPattern = string.Concat(escapedLowerCaseSearchPattern,
                                                        "*");
var queryParser = new QueryParser(/* my lucene version*/,
                                  fieldName,
                                  /* a reference to a static instance of my LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer */);
var query = queryParser.Parse(prefixEscapedLowerCaseSearchPattern);
```

**1st testcase**

```
searchPattern: Auß
fieldName: Test
```

actual:

```
{Test:auß*}
```

expected:

```
{Test:auss*}
```

**2nd testcase**

```
searchPattern: Auß test
fieldName: Test
```

actual:

```
{Test:auß Test:test*}
```

expected:

```
{Test:auss test*}
```

So, how can I utilize my `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer` with a `Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser` to get the expected result? (or is there any other solution??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've tried this:

```
var escapedLowerCaseSearchPattern = QueryParser.Escape(searchPattern);
var prefixEscapedLowerCaseSearchPattern = string.Concat("\"",
                                                        escapedLowerCaseSearchPattern,
                                                        "*\"");
var queryParser = new QueryParser(/* my lucene version */,
                                  fieldName,
                                  /* a reference to a static instance of my LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer */);
var query = queryParser.Parse(prefixEscapedLowerCaseSearchPattern);
```

This generates the very valid query

```
{Test:auss*}
```

but does somehow not work...

I remembered that I got results when I've used the `Lucene.Net.Search.PrefixQuery` with non umlaut searchPatterns ...
Then, I thought ... well ... just use the `Lucene.Net.Index.Term` inside my `Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery`-instance for a `Lucene.Net.Search.PrefixQuery`:

```
var escapedLowerCaseSearchPattern = QueryParser.Escape(searchPattern);
var prefixEscapedLowerCaseSearchPattern = string.Concat("\"",
                                                        escapedLowerCaseSearchPattern,
                                                        "\"");
var queryParser = new QueryParser(/* my lucene version */,
                                  fieldName,
                                  /* a reference to a static instance of my LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer */);
var termQuery = (TermQuery) queryParser.Parse(prefixEscapedLowerCaseSearchPattern);
var term = termQuery.Term;
var prefixQuery = new PrefixQuery(term);
```

BOOOM!

This generates the same query (`{Test:auss*}`), but somehow yields a result ... I don't know why, though ...